# Reading JSONs into a pandas DataFrame and adding/merging them

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm reading a csv file into my pandas DataFrame. One of the columns *my_json_col* is JSON (in string).

I apply the read_json function to *my_json_col*

```
   df['json_col'].apply(read_json)
```

so this JSON:

```
   [{"C5": 4, "Descr": "descr1"}, {"C6"": 2, "Descr": ""descr2"}, {"C8": 9, "Descr": ""descr5"}]
```

would become

```
     C5    C6    C8       Descr
 0   4.0   NaN   NaN      descr1
 1   NaN   2.0   NaN      descr2
 2   NaN   NaN   9.0      descr5
```

and

```
     [{"C1":  7, "Descr": "descr3""}, {"C5"":  3, "Descr"": "descr1""}, {"C4": 5, "Descr": "descr1"}]
```

would become

```
      C1    C4     C5   Descr
  0   7.0   NaN   NaN   descr3
  1   NaN   NaN   NaN   descr4
  2   NaN   5.0   3.0   descr1
```

"Adding" those two dataframes should give me:

```
     C1    C4    C5    C6     C8      Descr
 0   NaN   5.0   7.0   NaN    NaN     descr1
 1   NaN   NaN   NaN   2.0    NaN     descr2
 2   7.0   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     descr3
 3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     descr4
 4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    9.0     descr5
```

Here the numbers 3 and 4 are added C1's descr1.

Now I have columns C1-C9 in my JSONs (not all of them present in every JSON), which are numbers.

I also have the column Descr with values descr1-descr5 which are text.

I have many of those JSONs and my goal is to add them together so in the end I i have numbers added together and Column Descr has values descr1-descr5.

```
   C1   C2    C3   C4   C5   C6   C7   C7   C9    Descr
 0                                                descr1
 1           added numbers                        descr2
 2           added numbers                        descr3 
 3                                                descr4
 4                                                descr5
```

I've tried merges and sums without any result. Maybe I shouldn't use apply(read_json) and instead have a different starting point? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`, for avoid `0` instead `NaN`s add `min_count=1` parameter:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=True).groupby('Descr', as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
print (df)
    Descr   C1   C4   C5   C6   C8
0  descr1  NaN  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
1  descr2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  descr3  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  descr4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  descr5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0
```

Last for change order of columns:

```
df = df[df.columns[1:].tolist() + df.columns[:1].tolist()]
print (df)
    C1   C4   C5   C6   C8   Descr
0  NaN  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN  descr1
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  descr2
2  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  descr3
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  descr4
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0  descr5
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer').groupby('Descr', as_index=False).sum()
```

```py
    Descr   C5  C6  C8  C1  C4
0   descr1  7.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0
1   descr2  0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   descr3  0.0 0.0 0.0 7.0 0.0
3   descr5  0.0 0.0 9.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: thanks for this! it works for two dataframes. but i have many of them in my column my_json_col. Can i use a lambda to apply the merge for every single one?

Comment: @artofdoe - then need `concat` with list of DataFrames, check another answer.